# Neural Network predicts only one class - binary classification and balanced dataset

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, classification

The goal of my work is to predict whether the three month return of a given stock will outperform or not the market (respectively classes 1 and 0) using fundamental data as features. The two classes are just slightly imbalanced: 0: 7835 observations and 1: 9933 observations (that is 44.1% and 55.9%). The problem is that my simple model predicts only the positive class for all the instances. How to solve the problem? I already tried to tweak some Hyperparameters (batch size, learning rate, number of layers, number of neurons per layer) but the best I achieved is a 99% prediction for the positive class and 1% for the other class.

The code is the following:

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)
X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu', input_dim=np.array(X_train).shape[1]))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')) 

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', 
         optimizer='adam',
         metrics=['accuracy']) 

history = model.fit(X_train, np.array(y_train), epochs=50)

score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose = 1)
```

The input data are as follows:

```
X_train

array([[8.22558113e-01, 2.57404768e-06, 1.89754460e-11, ...,
    1.77373849e-05, 5.68104337e-01, 4.07611328e-04],
   [8.22565854e-01, 2.57497415e-06, 1.33213703e-11, ...,
    1.77373846e-05, 5.68070546e-01, 4.07805946e-04],
   [8.22541701e-01, 2.57229903e-06, 1.36541830e-11, ...,
    1.77373842e-05, 5.30571708e-01, 4.07568375e-04],
   ...,
   [8.22567337e-01, 2.57182629e-06, 1.36476410e-11, ...,
    1.77373846e-05, 5.68054845e-01, 4.07615103e-04],
   [8.22535352e-01, 2.57212835e-06, 1.36486715e-11, ...,
    1.77373849e-05, 5.68030190e-01, 4.07519838e-04],
   [8.22535480e-01, 2.57180477e-06, 1.36460472e-11, ...,
    1.77373837e-05, 5.68007221e-01, 4.07568375e-04]])

y_train

array([[0],
   [1],
   [1],
   ...,
   [1],
   [0],
   [0]])
```

Comment: Could you print out the first few rows in y_train? The binary_crossentropy requires inputs give like [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/binary_crossentropy).

Comment: Nothing in this piece of code causes the problem. I just checked locally. Any idea what else could be to blame here?

Comment: Maybe too noisy inputs? However, the same data fed to a Forest Classifier output a balanced prediction.

Comment: Have you tried to give the last layer two neurons and use the softmax activation function. You will need also to one hot encode the labels in order to get probabilities for each class.

Comment: How should I transform the label vector (of shape (14312, 1)) into an array of shape (None, 2)?